# Java Hash values: how to make them efficiently comparable?

Tags: java, hash, comparison, comparable

I have pairs of hash values like

> 1. 128ecf542a35ac5270a87dc740918404;d603ac0c04b9d08974482ae7fd4cf55
> 2. a1288b1c7e2257a90bad9bdfb7690fbb;f23828e312d90cb7fdadd6479236119c
> 3. ................................;................................

I would like to make each pair comparable with other, meaning:

> 128ecf542a35ac5270a87dc740918404;d603ac0c04b9d08974482ae7fd4cf55d

stays as it is;

in the case of

> d603ac0c04b9d08974482ae7fd4cf55d;128ecf542a35ac5270a87dc74091840

4, it should become

> 128ecf542a35ac5270a87dc740918404;d603ac0c04b9d08974482ae7fd4cf55d

My main goal is to have a certain function which compares two hash values of one pair and returns a pair with values ordered in it according to some rule. The rule itself does not matter, the only requirement is, it should be extremely fast and should always give the same result given that input is either (unique1,unique2) or (unique2,unique1)

Thx!

One obvious , but inefficient way to do it would be to sum only the numbers contained in each hash value and compare them and put the hash value with the smaller sum as the first element in the pair and the bigger one in the second position.

Comment: The question is whether it is efficient and always guarantees the same output given that the pair has same hash values, but with the position exchanged?

Comment: `a.compareTo(b) == -b.compareTo(a)` if that is what you mean.  Most things are efficient compared with doing an MD5. ;)

Comment: how do you store the coupled hash values? are they in separate field, or are they just a concatenated string as you wrote it down, like "hashA1;hashA2" == "hashA2;hashA1" ?

Comment: concatenated string or better a csv format :-)

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/818375/illeatyourpuppies the interpretation is that two hash values separated with ; are a pair

Comment: @Bob Of course it's symmetrical. See the Javadoc. As to efficiency, no comparison of N bytes can be O(1) for N > 8. I don't see what your actual question is here. If it's real, it's been answered.

Answer (score 5):

Just compare the two strings with the usual string comparison (`compareTo`) and put the smaller one first. This will guarantee what you want. I expect this to be very cheap, because in practice the hash values will differ already in the first few chars, and the comparison then doesn't need to look at the rest of the strings. Furthermore, accessing and comparing a very low number of bytes (as in your example) is so cheap anyway that you will be able to see a performance impact only if you do this very often compared to the other operations your program does.

If you don't have the values as strings, but as byte arrays or something like this, just implement a simple lexicographical comparison on your own.

Comment: The complexity of compareTo as string is already O(number of characters in it). So since each hash value has the same length, it will be O(n), given that the hash value has the length n?

Comment: I am looking for something with O(1) :-), not sure if it is possible.

Comment: The complexity is O(n), right, but you won't find a solution with a smaller complexity (you can always construct cases where you need to look at all chars in order to determine the order). Also note that complexity is not the same as performance, but talks about worst-case performance. Best-case performance in this case is O(1). As I said, I expect average-case performance to be quite good, and you should care about that.

Comment: Yeah, but we, CS people, use the best case complexity only to show how bad an algorithm performs. The worst case would then be to show how acceptable an algorithm is. Maybe, I should give up my idea of having O(1), and stick with the standard solution of CompareTo();

Comment: How would you ever get an o(1) algorithm for this?

Comment: Good question, it was my blind try. As Philipp wrote, it is highly probable that two hash values differ from each other by their first characters or two. The probability of going through all characters is like 0.0000-E. Average complexity is I think almost O(1)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I've just read through your question again and main goal. **My answer is for comparing two pairs**.

If you want to order the two hash values in a pair really go with linearly comparing the two hash and on the first mismatch of characters put the lower value first. Chances are big that values will differ on the first few bytes already.

---

I don't think you can do it in Java but you may create a function for it in C/ASM then use it from Java through JNI.

Let's see: These are pairs of 32 byte hash values. You know where the pairs are separated at ';' byte 32.

Let be your coupled hash values as `hahsA := (hA1;hA2)` and `hashB := (hB1;hB2)`

You take the first pair:

1) get 0-15 and 33-49 bytes to two SSE registers and XOR it

```
hashA[0-15] := ( hashA1[0-15] XOR hashA2[0-15] ).
```

2) get 16-31 and 50-65 bytes to SSE registers and XOR it too

```
hashA[16-31] := ( hashA1[16-31] XOR hashA2[16-31] ).
```

Now you have two SSE registers filled with the XOR of the first and second 16 bytes of your couple:

```
XMM0: hashA[0-15]
XMM1: hashA[16-31]
```

You take the second pair and do the same thing. You have 8 SSE registers so you may not need to get the the value out of the register after 2).

Now you have:

```
XMM0: hA[0-15]
XMM1: hA[16-31]
XMM2: hB[0-15]
XMM3: hB[16-31]


if( XMM0 == XMM2 AND XMM1 == XMM3 ) then hA and hB are equal.
```

Of course if your hash codes are grater than 32 bytes, you need to make further steps, but assuming your hashcodes are all the same length, this algorithm takes:

1) load two 16 bytes and xor = 3 instructions
2) 3 instructions

1) and 2) again for second couple: 6 instructions
finally 2 instructions for compare and 1 instruction for AND

That sums up for something like 15 instructions for each comparing couples, not measuring function calls. I cannot say it is O(1) because if hash values are greater the number of instructions are growing as well.

If efficiency really matters this is a way to go. But anyways, I don't think you can do it less than O(n) because you have to compare all the characters.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to optimize the case where two strings are unequal, and the implementation of `String.equals(Object)` already does this.

However, the case where the two strings are equal but not `==` is inherently `O(N)`.

Now it is possible to improve on that under certain circumstances:

- you to be able to add an extra private field to the object,
- the objects' state must be stable with respect to the `equals` operator, and
- the same set of object instances need to be compared repeatedly.

Under those preconditions, there is an algorithm that tends to `O(1)`.  However, you can't apply it to hashes represented as String values because the 1st and (probably) 3rd conditions don't hold.